# What’s the best way to only allow a file to be opened with multiple people’s authorisation?

Tags: passwords, file-encryption, one-time-password

Is there software available that makes it easy for multiple authorisations to be required before a file can be opened? The simplest solution I've found online is to encrypt a file with a password, split the passwords into multiple pieces and give each user a password fragment, but this requires them all to be physically present or log in remotely to type their segment of the password if they're going to enter it without revealing it.

The ideal way might be to provide some kind of temporary code, something like [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password), which could then be sent to open the file on a given occasion but wouldn't be useful thereafter.

Is there an easy way to do something like this securely?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Do you have control over the users? User accounts? The devices used? Can the file be served from a cloud service? There are lots of ways to do this but we don't know the limitations or resources you have.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I’d like the file to be stored locally on arbitrary users' machines, so no control over any of the above.

Comment: I'm really not sure how that could be possible.

Comment: Can't the people who do the authorization co-ordinate themselves and simply one of them then performs the authorization? If there are lots of different files across different sets of people, maybe you need to really re-think your authorization methods and make it so it isn't so convoluted.

Comment: As I said, the brute force solution eg for two users would be for user one to type their half of the password and user two to then log in remotely to type their half. I was wondering if there was a way to make something like that less clunky.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can help you, because your problem is not clearly explained, but maybe [Shamir's secret sharing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) can help you. You can use this to divide a secret (like an encryption key or a password) among multiple persons safely and with better properties than just splitting a very long password.

Comment: TOTP (and similar algorithms) needs an application to check the validity of the token. This application must never be executed on a computer under the control of someone attempting illegitimately access the confidential data, because it could then be hacked in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple way would be to encrypt the file in sequence with the keys of all its owners. Algorithmically it would be:

```
orig  -- key A -->  encA   # and destroys orig
encA  -- key B -->  encB   # and destroys encA
encB  -- key C -->  encC   # and destroys encB
```

To recover the original file, you would just do the opposite

```
encC  --> key C -->  encB
encB  --> key B -->  encA
encA  --> key A -->  orig
```

The good point is that the decryption does not need to be simultaneous, because each key owner could just send their partial decryption to the next one. The bad point is that you should find a way to prevent A to keep a copy of orig or encA: if they do, they would be able to access the original data without the other keys.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense but as you say relies on trusting A... It would be great if there were some way to perform this process in real-time rather than sequentially...

Comment: @tds03725: many encrypting tools allow to chain the operations in a pipeline. You just need an interface where A, B, and C enter their keys and the pipeline starts when the 3 keys are present. But then A, B and C have to trust the interface not to steal their keys...

Comment: The file would have to be passed from one user and system to the other in sequence. And this is a static linear sequence.